# CODE1 at SPOJ - cannot solve it

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am trying to solve the problem *Secret Code* on [SPOJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOJ), and it's obviously a math problem.

[The full problem](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/CODE1/)

For those who are lazy to go and read, it's like this:

```
a0, a1, a2, ..., an - sequence of N numbers
B - a Complex Number (has both real and imaginary components)
X = a0 + a1*B + a2*(B^2) + a3*(B^3) + ... + an*(B^n)
```

So if you are given B and X, you should find a0, a1, ..an.
I don't know how or where to start, because not even N is known, just X and B.

The problem is not as easy as expressing a number in a base B, because B is a complex number.

How can it be solved?

Comment: Actually, the problem is stated as a programming problem on the website.  Check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is that `a0 .. an` are not arbitrary numbers, they're *integers* (otherwise, this wouldn't be possible in general).  You're given the number `X` , and are asked to express it in base `B`.  Why don't you start by working a few examples for a specific value of `B`?

If I asked you to write 17 in base 2, would you be able to do that?  Can you find a way to generalize the algorithm you use to bases other than 2?

Comment: Can you clarify your suggestion about expressing in base B ? For your ex, i don't know how to write 17 in base 2 ?

Comment: @VaioIsBorn - here's some info about converting between number bases, it should also help you see what the problem asks for: http://www.brainjammer.com/math/bases/ and http://www.math.grin.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/152/97F/Readings/student-binary